# Запись и чтение чисел из програмного канала pipe

Tags: c, linux, pipes

Нужно записать в канал три числа, а затем считать их и вывести на экран. Что то типа:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int fd[2], result;
size_t size;
double a=1.3,b=2.4,c=555555;
double resstring[3];
pipe(fd);
write(fd[1], b, 1);
size = read(fd[0], resstring, 1);
printf("%d\n",resstring[0]);
```

Только не работает пример вовсе. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы неправильно используете write/read. 
В write нужно передавать указатель, и правильно указать ее размер. Ваши переменные имеют тип `double`, их размер не равен 1. То же самое и с `read`. `write(fd[1], &b, sizeof(double))`
Чтобы вывести на экран переменную типа `double` нужно использовать модификатор `%lf`.

```
#include <sys/types.h>                                                                                        
#include <unistd.h>                                                                                           
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                            
int main()                                                                                                    
{                                                                                                             
    int fd[2], result;                                                                                        
    size_t size;                                                                                              
    double a=1.3,b=2.4,c=555555;                                                                              
    double resstring[3];                                                                                      
    pipe(fd);                                                                                                 
    write(fd[1], &b, sizeof(double));                                                                         
    size = read(fd[0], resstring, sizeof(double));                                                            
    printf("%lf\n",resstring[0]);                                                                             
}
```

Comment: Благодарю. Но как ввести и вывести три числа?
Сделать write(fd[1], &число, sizeof(double)); три раза подряд или можно это сделать более красиво?

Comment: double arr[] = {1.3, 2.4, 5555}; write(fd[1], arr, 3*sizeof(double));